# How do I convert all the citations to static text in Microsoft Word 365?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I know that to convert one citation to a static text, I need to choose this option in the pop-up by clicking the dots next to the citation.

But what if I want to convert all of them to the static text, as my standard isn't present in the MW libraries? Is there a way to do it?

I've found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-convert-all-citations-to-static-text/494efb8f-8741-4338-ae35-2c0aea6f74e2) and [this](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm), but there's no solution for MW365, as far as I see.

The other solution of the problem might be a guide to installing macros in MW365.

Comment: I don’t think MW365 has anything new in this area, and there’s no reason why the VBA Your first link points to wouldn’t work in 365. Did you try it?

Comment: @yokki I don't know how to insert such a code into macros in MW365. Should I reformulate the question into this one? I'll add a sentence.

Comment: I tend to assume that MW365 means *desktop* Word 2016/2019/365 - if that's what you're dealing with, the second link you have covers it for the Windows version, but lumps it all under "Word 2010 and later". Windows Word 365/2016/2019 is very similar. Mac Word is different, though you could probably piece together how to do it from the second link. However, if you are using the web or device versions, there's no VBA support, very little support for anything to do with fields, and the only equivalent would be to use the new Office-JS API - couldn't vene tell you if that could do this job, sorry!

Comment: @yokki thanks a lot, I've got desktop Word 365 indeed. I'll try it in a day or two and tell you if it worked.

Comment: @yokki it doesn't work. doing everything manually))